# Solving an integral equation by Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, integral-equations

I have to solve the following exercise. Using the Fourier transform to solve the integral equation
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\frac{1}{x-y}dy.
$$

Some hints?

Comment: Do you mean verify that you can find a function f so that this equality is true?

Comment: Yes, I have to find $f(y)$.

Comment: You should add a precise definition: due to the singularity at $y=x$, the RHS doesn't make sense as an ordinary integral. It may be meant as a Cauchy principal value, but in that case, you should add (or link to) the correct definition. Maybe you don't like doing *any* research for your exercises, but why do you expect others to be eager to do that for you?

Comment: Fourier transform both sides. The right hand side is then a transform of a  convolution. Use your FT table and get an algebraic equation for F(w), the transform of f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $h(x)={1\over x}$ therefore $$f(x)*h(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$where $*$ denotes convolution operator. Taking Fourier transform from both sides we get:$$F(\omega)H(\omega)=\pi e^{-|\omega|}\to F(\omega)=isgn(\omega)e^{-|\omega|}=ie^{-\omega}u(\omega)-ie^{\omega}u(-\omega)\to \\f(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: The student asked for a hint.